# Storing personal quotations

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to stop SQL Injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php)

I'm curious what all functions I should run on a text string that's a quote before I store it in my database.

I want to handle it if it has single quotes contained in it as well as other double quotes or anything else.

Comment: Which RDBMS? Either way, escape it.

Comment: How is this a duplicate.

Comment: 'duplicate': Essentially the same question, phrased differently.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

in terms of php you should use `trim() and stripslashes()` and if you are using mysql then `mysql_real_escape_string()`

you can use them in this order:

first `stripslashes()` then

trim() then

```
mysql_real_escape_string()
```

Comment: So your saying mysql_real_escape_string(trim(stripslashes($quote)))?

Comment: why -1 can you please tell me the reason?

Comment: @user1333299 yes,sort of this kind,if it works for you

Comment: @user1333299 you should use trim() if you are not sure about that the input string's unnecessary white space at the start & at the end

Comment: "This answer is not useful", as it says on the down arrow. What problems, do `stripslashes` and `trim` solve in this case?

Comment: @Piskvor by using trim() you can be on safe side in case,if you are taking input from user side .I mean to say that you can remove white spaces

Comment: Yes, I know what `trim()` does; it's unclear to me *why* should I do that. Are you claiming that whitespace is unsafe? How exactly? Any examples?

Comment: @Piskvor i am not saying that it is a security breach,i am just saying that it's a good practice to use trim()

Comment: No, it's not a "good practice". If you seriously claim that whitespace should be stripped "just to be on the safe side", as it's (in your opinion) potentially dangerous. I suggest that you don't go near any database, at all, "just to be on the safe side". They're dangerous things, y'know. (As for `stripslashes()`, now that's pure cargo-cult: applying that function going *from* application layer *to* database layer won't make the string "safer", plus it will introduce a host of other problems.)

Answer (score 3):

From the most effective to the least, there are four things you can do (I'm assuming MySQL here, as it's the most common combination with PHP):

- Use parametrized queries and you'd be spared this whole "escaping" ordeal.
- If parametrized queries are not an option, use mysql_real_escape_string().
- `addslashes()` and `stripslashes()` might be effective in specific circumstances - but do not use them unless you know *exactly* what you're doing and unless you're certain that it won't make your code vulnerable to multi-byte injection attacks.
- Approaches like "stripping out whitespace" are completely useless here. "Cargo-cult programming", you might call that.

Answer (score 1):

Use `mysql_real_escape_string()` if you use MySQL.